# How to change my excel file values usning python

Tags: python, pandas

I have an ecxel file like this and I want the numbers in the date field to be converted to a date like (2021.7.22) and replaced in the date field again using python
[image]

Comment: Please, read the SO tour page about how to write a question. You need to show to the community more effort when writing your question. Probably this question will be closed. Edit your question, add details, show people you tried to solve you problem at least.

Comment: take a look at `opencv` and `pywin32`.

Comment: maybe first read excel to pandas, next use pandas functions to modify it, and finally save it back to excel file

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
dfs = pd.read_excel('Test.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
output = {}
for ws, df in dfs.items():
    if 'date' in df.columns:
        df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].apply(lambda x: f'{str(x)[:4]}.{str(x)[4:6 if len(str(x)) > 7 else 5]}.{str(x)[-2:]}')).dt.date
    output[ws] = df
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('TestOutput.xlsx')
for ws, df in output.items():
    df.to_excel(writer, index=None, sheet_name=ws)
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

For each worksheet containing the column `date` in the input xlsx file, it will convert the integer it finds to a date, assuming that the month portion may be 1 or 2 digits and that the day portion is always a full 2 digits. If the actual month/day protocol in your data is different, you can adjust the logic accordingly.

The code creates a new output xlsx reflecting the above changes.

Comment: @dark diamond Do you need additional help with your question?